# FFMPEG mp4 instead of flv

Tags: video, ffmpeg

really struggling with ffmpeg at the moment, after a few days of messing about with it i have managed to get it to almost do what i want!

I have an audio track and a series of images that are to be converted into a slideshow displaying each image for 5 seconds.

```
-r 1/5 -i C:\ffmpeg\image-%02d.bmp -i C:\ffmpeg\music.mp3 -qscale:v 2 -shortest -codec:a copy C:\ffmpeg\output.flv
```

I can get this to work as a flv but not as any other format. I need to have it in either an mp4, avi, wmv, or mov format.

I can convert this to a wmv but the file size is HUGE (about 100meg/min)!

```
 -i C:\ffmpeg\output.flv -vcodec wmv1 -acodec adpcm_ima_wav  C:\ffmpeg\output.wmv
```

Can anyone please help me either:

- output the original code to mp4,wmv,mov,or avi (with a reasonable file size ideally less than 10 meg per min)
- convert the flv to either an mp4,wmv,mov, or avi with again a reasonable file size)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create an mp4 file containing H.264 video and AAC-LC audio:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i C:\ffmpeg\image-%02d.bmp -i C:\ffmpeg\music.mp3 -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:v libx264 -b:v 1200k -codec:a libfdk_aac C:\ffmpeg\output.mp4
```

This requires that your `ffmpeg` was configured to support the `libx264` H.264 encoder and the `libfdk_aac` AAC-LC encoder.

A video bitrate of 1200 kb/s (`-b:v 1200k`), when combined with the audio, should be about 10 MB/min.  See the [ffmpeg x264 encoding guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for some other ways to control the video bitrate.

If you don't have the `libfdk_aac` encoder you could instead use the built-in experimental AAC encoder (replace `-codec:a libfdk_aac` with `-codec:a aac -strict experimental`) or [another AAC encoder](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide).  Or you could use the original mp3 audio (`-codec:a copy`), although mp3 audio is not as common in an mp4 container so your player may not support that.